# Create columns from 1 column that contain lists

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp, preprocessor

So I have a pandas dataframe that something like this

| text | categories |
| --- | --- |
| First text | ['Tech', 'Business'] |
| Second text | ['Women', 'India', 'Tech'] |

I want to convert it to

| text | Business | India | Tech | Women |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First text | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Second text | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have 200 unique categories, so manual is not an option.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Show what you have tried so far (code) in a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a df similar to yours

data = [['First text', "['Tech', 'Business']"], ['Second text', "['Women', 'India', 'Tech']"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text', 'categories'])

# We get rid of the quotes from the lists

df["categories"] = df["categories"].apply(eval)

# New df with zeros

new = df[['text']].copy()
new[['Business', 'India', 'Tech', 'Women']] = 0

# Loop

for count, value in enumerate(df["categories"]):
    for j in value:
        if j == "Business":
            new.iloc[count, new.columns.get_loc('Business')] = 1
        elif j == "India":
            new.iloc[count, new.columns.get_loc('India')] = 1
        elif j == "Tech":
            new.iloc[count, new.columns.get_loc('Tech')] = 1
        elif j == "Women":
            new.iloc[count, new.columns.get_loc('Women')] = 1

print(new.head())
```

Not the prettiest code, but it should work.